# How can I send an automated reply to the sender and all recipients with Procmail?

Tags: procmail

I'd like to create a procmail recipe or Perl or shell script that will send an auto response to the original sender as well as anybody that was copied (either To: or cc:) on the original email.

Example:

bob@example.com writes an email to john@example.com and paul@example.com (in the To: field).  Copies are sent via cc: to rob@example.com and alice@example.com.

I'd like the script to send an auto response to the original sender (bob@example.com) and everybody else that was sent a copy of the email (john@example.com, paul@example.com, rob@example.com and alice@example.com).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish this using the [this procmail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-Procmail/lib/Mail/Procmail.pm) module for Perl 5. You could also just use the procmail configuration files to do this as well.

Here's an example of our procmail configuration sending e-mails "through" a perl script.

```
:0fw
* < 500000
| /etc/smrsh/decode_subject.pl
```

I hope that helps get ya started.

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM=`formail -rtzxTo:`
CC=`formail -zxTo: -zxCc: | tr '\n' ,`

:0c
| ( echo To: "$FROM"; echo Cc: "$CC"; echo Subject: auto-reply; \
    echo; echo Please ignore. ) \
  | $SENDMAIL -oi -t
```

A well-formed auto-reply should set some additional headers etc; but this should hopefully be enough to get you started.  See also http://porkmail.org/era/mail/autoresponder-faq.html

Depending on you flavor of `tr` you might need to encode the newline differently; not all implementations of `tr` understand the `'\n'` format.  Try with `'\012'` or a literal newline in single quotes if you cannot get this to work.